# Can't scroll everywhere inside a scrollViewer

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I have a little problem. I want to put a view inside a stackPanel with a scrollbar. Basically, this is how I try to do this :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FirstTemplate">
    <vw:FirstView DataContext="{Binding}"></vw:FirstView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="SecondTemplate">
    <vw:SecondView DataContext="{Binding}"></vw:SecondView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ThirdTemplate">
    <vw:ThirdView DataContext="{Binding}"></vw:ThirdView>
</DataTemplate>

<selector:DimensionTemplateSelector x:Key="SomeTemplateSelector"   
    FirstTemplate="{StaticResource FirstTemplate}"  
    SecondTemplate="{StaticResource SecondTemplate}" 
    ThirdTemplate="{StaticResource ThirdTemplate}">
</selector:DimensionTemplateSelector>


<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SomeTemplateSelector}"  
                        Content="{Binding ASelectedValue}" />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The problem with this code is that I can scroll with the mouse wheel only if my mouse is over the scrollbar zone. If my mouse is inside the stackPanel (so, inside the ScrollViewer tags) but not directly over the scrollbar zone, trying to scroll with the mouse wheel won't result in anything.

I'm very not sure, but it seem like I should define a behaviour to my contentControl so it can handle scrolling. Anyone know how to do that or have a better explanation ?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you have stored in the DataContext? Different type or not? Can this all associate, for example, in ListBox where normally works selector templates and scrolling works correctly. By the way, if you just set the items in the StackPanel (TextBlock's) with a ScrollViewer, it works for me as it should.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I have three differents views. One with listBox, the two other with differents controls, but only the listBox is interesting. I set the scrollViewer on the stackPanel, because I try something like that                                <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">           and it doesn't work

Comment: To say exactly what the problem is, show all the source code, that is where the ListBox and what data you're there you load. Without the code hard to say what the problem is.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem. The scrollViewer wasn't need. Just have to set a size to my contentControl. Thank you